# Factorize $2a^3 - b^3 - c^3$

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I need to factorize the expression $2a^3 - b^3 - c^3$. I see that one zero is achieved when $a=b=c$, but I can't find the factor(s).

Comment: It's not clear how you conclude that $a=b=c$ implies that value must be a factor. That would mean that for any $b+c=2a$, you'd have a solution to $2a^3-b^3-c^3$, which is not true. For example, when $b=2a,c=0$, then $2a^3\neq b^3$ in general.

Comment: It is not always possible to factor every polynomial. Why do you think you can factor this one? Also, in what sense of factoring?

Comment: I want to compute (in a numerically stable way) $2a^3-b^3-c^3$ for large values of $a,b,c$ such that $a \approx b \approx c$. My hope is that there is a factorization of the expression that can help me achieve this, just like $a^3-b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+c^2)$ does for the first order differences.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're looking for factors that are polynomials with integer coefficients.

Your polynomial is not factorizable in this sense. To see why, look at what happens when $b=0,c=1$. You get $2a^3-1$, which you cannot factor over the integers.

Answer (score 1):

Writing
$$
2a^3-b^3-c^3=a^3-b^3+a^3-c^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)+(a-c)(a^2+ac+c^2)
$$
We can see that we have simple factorizations if $a=b$ or $a=c$ or $b=c$ and also for $b+a=c$. But in general we cannot find a factorization for all real values of $a,b,c$.

Answer (score -2):

$$2X^3-b^3-c^3=0$$

So $X=\sqrt[3]{\frac {b^3+c^3} 2}$ is a root, now do long division and use the quadratic formula.